# HTML line split between two pages, when try to convert pdf via NRECO

Tags: c#, nreco

I am using `<ul><li></li>....</ul>` to display data. When I found to much data then some splits between two pages. PFA image[image]

I tried with below CSS:

```
ul { page-break-inside: avoid !important; }
```

AND

```
li { page-break-inside: avoid !important; }
```

Comment: Maybe your list <ul> is placed inside <table>? wkhtmltopdf handles correctly 'page-break-inside:avoid' only for top-level elements.

Comment: Yes It is wrapped inside <table>.

Comment: Then, you need to change the layout and avoid outer <table> to get correct page breaks.